# Related to derivative of Modified Bessel I function wrt the order

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, bessel-functions

I recently met some problems related to the modified Bessel I funtions. Let $I(\nu,x):=I_\nu(x)$, and $I'_\nu(\nu,x):=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \nu}I(\nu,x)$. 
Using maple, it seems that $Re(\dfrac{I'_\nu(\nu,x)}{I(\nu,x)})<0$ for any 
$x>0$ and $Re(\nu)>0$. I want to know if there exist some results about it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.37 and references cited there.